# Angular 4. Remove file in production environment

Tags: angular

I have Angular 4 project and use some of my files(or classes) only in dev environment. 
But how to remove them from the build for production environment(ng build --env=prod)?

Thanks.

Comment: Just trying to get some background. Why would you want to remove those classes in production ?

Comment: Because I don't use them in production. That mostly stubs that I use instead of some services

Answer (score 1):

The production environnement uses the AOT Compilation therefore you can customize the build options by creating a file with the name `tsconfig-aot.json` in your  `src`folder (for more infos check [Ahead of Time Compilation](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#compile-with-aot) ) then you can use the `exclude` array to specify the excluded files for example:

```
"exclude": [
  "test.ts",
   "**/*.spec.ts"
 ]
```